# how can i make this container to be in as footer in the screen with css in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

I am doing react native for my project and I made this code:

```
  <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
          <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
            <Image
              source={require('../../assets/pic/footer.png')} // Provide the correct path to your image
              style={styles.logoImage}
            />
          </View>
    </View>
```

and I want to keep it down on the screen as you can see in the picture there is a space between the container and the end of the page.

I did try to make it

```
 logoContainer: {
    width: 32,
    height: 36,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

and still did not work, i can do it margin and make it fit my screen but is there any better solution so it always has a footer look ever the screen size?
here is a picture :

[image]

as well as I use these :

```
safeArea: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
```

Comment: Please add full code. If you have SafeAreaView in the layout that is the reason. The space seen in the image is the bottom safe area.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS notch screen devices, If you wrap your screen with a SafeAreaView so you need to remove the 'bottom' value from your 'edges' array as follows:

```
<SafeAreaView edges={{
  bottom: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 'maximum',
}}></SafeAreaView>
```

This will help you get rid of the extra bottom space that's covered by the SafeAreaView.

You can find more information here: https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context#edges